# How to block serialiazation for 50 variables

Tags: java

How to block serialization for 50 variables, is there any way other than using `transient`, for example if we have 50 variables declared:

```
public int age;
public String name;
public String description;
...
```

Comment: By declaring them `transient`. Same works also for 100, 150 and 200 variables. If you have 50 variables in a class, it's probably badly designed and therefore it serves you right to have to type `transient` 50 times.

Comment: Write a custom serializer for the class. containing those fields. Well documented.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply, how to write a custom serializer for a class?